# Wordpress author name hiding

Tags: wordpress

I have created a website and Now I want to write a post. The website managed by wordpress.org. The  problem is, in the published page, the my email is showing on the page as author. How to hide this?

Actually I want the remove the mail from the post : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Humm, when you say hosted, is it fair to assume that you are using a hosted version or wordpress? If so, you should be able to tweak the display of your posts in your wordpress settings. For my theme, I can twiddle whether or not an author tag appears in a blog post by going to theme options > blog page. Your mileage may vary depending on your theme.

[image]

If your theme does not let you turn off the author tag, you may want to just change your name to something other than your email address. If I want a name to appear rather than an email address, I can set a displayable name in the wordpress user settings. I just edit the user to include a name string.

[image: users menu]

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Can you tell me more about your site? What theme are your using? The screenshot doesn't look like the default wordpress 2014 theme, so I am trying to reduce guessing on my part :)

Comment: If you are comfortable with PHP, check out how to [manually alter wordpress post metadata styling](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section)